# How to handle animations with behavior trees in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence, behavior-tree, animationcontroller

I'm working on an AI implementation in Unity, using the [Fluid Behaviour Tree](https://github.com/ashblue/fluid-behavior-tree) library and I was wondering how to handle the animations with the BT.

I'm building a character that can interact with the player, so when the player hits a specific key it should stop doing whatever it's doing and react by playing a proper animation. The animations are set up in an Animation Controller. The problem is I can't find a way how to detect if an animation is finished in order to continue with the rest of the tree. I've read that animations and BT's should be separated but I can't really imagine how to do that.

So here's my question: **how should animations be handled by a behaviour tree that's set up in Unity?** How can I provide the proper execution of the BT and perform the animations in their full length when needed?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? Also looking for the same.